# Restrict Find & Replace/SUBSTITUTE to specific text that may also occur in words

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, substitution

I have a mailing list with addresses in one column. There are duplicates, but not exact ones - in that some records have `ST` while others have `STREET`. I am looking to formalize the convention and just replace all `ST` with `STREET`. I am having trouble restricting Find and Replace, and even the `SUBSTITUTE` function, from correcting it when `ST` occurs in a word like "STONE". Are there any ways to specify that it should be only `ST`?

I have tried copying the data to another column and replacing all "spaces" with "-", which works if the `ST` occurs in the middle of the text string. However, if it occurred at the end, the result is simply "-ST". If I attempt to automate the correction of "-ST" it also changes addresses such as "-Stone-Field" to "-Streetone-Field".

I also tried search with spaces before and after, so " ST ", and the same problem when it comes to the end of the cell (because I would have to search for only " ST").

Comment: In your formula, first add spaces to begin and end of string, do your SUBSTITUTE, then use TRIM to remove the spaces you added.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Thats what I eventually ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to *list* examples that you are trying to deal with but a combination of replace `ST` (that's spaceSTspace) with `STREET` (that's spaceSTREETspace), `ST` (that's STspace) with `STREET` (that's STREETspace) and then:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,3)=" ST",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)&" STREET")
```

seems to cover most possibilities without being excessive.

Comment: Thanks, I had just come to the realization that i might need to use similar formula that you had after my initial pass through. That may be the best I can get. As far as Examples, its simple:

10276 FIELD STONE COURT
120 STATE ST

Using my initial "=SUBSTITUTE(C4,"ST","STREET")" did not work properly as expected. If i revise to:

10276-FIELD-STONE-COURT
120-STATE-ST

and then try to use =SUBSTITUTE(C4,"-ST","STREET"); it still doesn't work because the formula still replaces it in "-STONE".

Answer (score -1):

Replace " `ST` " with " `STREET` ".